# Custom header not accessible via AJAX in chrome version 60

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

We have a request whose response returns custom added response headers for authentication. We set these headers to local storage for further usage in the application.

```
 localStorage.setItem("X-LOCAL-TOKEN-REFRESH",request.getResponseHeader('X-Local-Token-Refresh'));
```

This issue appears in the new google chrome 60.0.3112.78 release.
It works absolutely fine in other browsers and previous chrome versions.

In the current version we get the value of  `request.getResponseHeader(X-Local-Token-Refresh)` as null, but the response header has the value in it.Below is the response header we get

```
 X-LOCAL-TOKEN:eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI5NzY2NDYwMTU2Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbImNvbS5wcm9qZWN0eC5zZWN1cml0eS5yZXBvc2l0b3J5LkF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uVXNlckRldGFpbHNTZXJ2aWNlJCRMYW1iZGEkNDAvNjkyMjkyNjE5QDM4Y2MyYTkyIl0sImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9kZXYudHJhbnNwb3J0by5pbiIsImlhdCI6MTUwMTU5ODk5NywiZ
```

Is it a bug that's causing the issue or some change in the implementation of getResponseHeader function is what we are unable to make out. Tried to check the realease docs, but to no success. Any information from the community would be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415480/warning-xhr-getallresponseheaders-in-chrome-60-returns-lowercase-header-fiel

Comment: @mplungjan Not sure why it did not come up while I was posting. Will try and add it as an answer! Kudos.

Comment: Let the guy answer his own question, then we can close yours as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XHR.getAllResponseHeaders() does not return headers as expected in Chrome 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415480/xhr-getallresponseheaders-does-not-return-headers-as-expected-in-chrome-60)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link, It helped us out. Hope it will help you out also.

[XHR.getAllResponseHeaders() does not return headers as expected in Chrome 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415480/xhr-getallresponseheaders-does-not-return-headers-as-expected-in-chrome-60)