# Chrome v60 Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, indexof, lowercase

Previous to Chrome v60 being released the following code worked in Chrome and recent version of Firefox

```
var deleteOccured = $.grep(headers, function (a) {
    return a.indexOf('DeleteOccured') != -1;
})[0].split(':')[1].trim();
```

Where "headers" are

```
DeleteOccured: false
```

When I debug the grep loop - `"DeleteOccured"` in Chrome is showing as all lowercase

And given that `indexOf` is case sensitive it breaks in Chrome and yet still works in FF

So am wondering - does anyone know what specifically changed in Chrome to cause this to start breaking (incidentally have already fixed it, but am still curious as to why)

Comment: Create a jsfiddle, please. My v60 returns `false`. You should mention that headers is an array.

Comment: `$.grep` expects the first argument to be an array, not a string.

Comment: Post an MCVE as a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Presumably `$.grep` is jQuery, which is a library. Apparently it [supports](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) "Chrome: (Current - 1) and Current", so first stop is jQuery support.

Comment: Confirming - headers is an array - I didnt not explain that I was just adding part of the array that is headers

And yes grep is jQuery - but it does not explain why in relation to headers, that FF keep the case of "DeleteOccured" but Chrome shows it has "deleteoccured"

One thing to note - the response headers in Chrome dev tools -> network tab - show DeleteOccured, not the lowercase that I am observing

Comment: Sample of full headers is

Connection:Keep-Alive

Content-Encoding:gzip

Content-Length:22

Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

Date:Wed, 09 Aug 2017 13:55:05 GMT

DeleteOccured:false

which is converted to headers, via this 

var headers = msg.headers.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ',').split(',');

Comment: So in Chrome, you just get a different `msg.headers` string, is that correct?

Comment: chrome is showing them as lower case in javascript, and yet in the network tab they retain their correct case

also note, there is no lowercase conversion being performed - the code above is "as is"

Comment: As an update to all - it is indeed something Chrome 60 introduced - where all xhr headers, whatever case they returned from server, Chrome makes them all lowercase :)

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/_oxlCPNsrck
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/99c274ae8e7d366261dcfb89e0b98e733fb9d5f4
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415480/xhr-getallresponseheaders-does-not-return-headers-as-expected-in-chrome-60

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XHR.getAllResponseHeaders() does not return headers as expected in Chrome 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415480/xhr-getallresponseheaders-does-not-return-headers-as-expected-in-chrome-60)